# Trigger, preventing user from deleting campaign unless criteria met

Tags: apex, trigger, class, design-patterns

Would love some guidance.

Criteria : Only the Campaign Owner can delete a campaign. If any contact member has a campaign member statuses passed 'Sent' then the campaign can not be deleted. I would need this to apply for all campaign Record types.

However, I would want anyone with a System Administrator profile to be able to perform Deletes.

I was thinking of creating the the following trigger

```
    trigger CampaignDeletePrevent on Campaign (before delete) {
if(Trigger.isBefore){
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        PreventCampaignDelete.campaignDelete(trigger.oldMap);  
    }}}
```

The trigger would then call the class "PreventCampaignDelete". Within the class i would have the appropriate logic.

```
public class PreventCampaignDelete{
public static void campaignDelete(Map<Id,Contact> contacts){}
```

Question is do you recommend this approach ? or have it all within the trigger?

Comment: I would go with the Separation of Concerns pattern (see Trailhead) and compose a `CampaignsService` with initial method `isDeleteable(set<ID> ids)`. Then the service can be invoked from various clients - Domain layer (trigger), VF controllers, REST services, etc.

Comment: Delete permission is hierarchy based, even if org wide defaults are read/write.  Are you sure none of the profiles have modify all on campaign?  Users in same role should *not* be able to delete others campaigns.  But users above them in role heirarchy should.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few gaps in the requirements but based on your initial idea:

1. Only campaign Owner can delete Campaigns. (This is granted pretty much as standard SFDC rights on Force.com sharing) You could reinforce it on the trigger if you want.
2. If any Campaign Member passed '**Send**' campaign can't be deleted. I assume that you are saying that the Campaign Member status is anything except 'Send'.
3. If the running user has 'System Administrators' profile can delete any campaign.

This code has not been tested and it is a guideline you can use. 
The trigger can be something like this:

```
trigger OnCampaingBeforeDelete on Campaign (before delete) {

List<Campaign> CampaignList = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, (SELECT Id, Status FROM CampaignMembers WHERE Status!='Send')
                               FROM Campaign WHERE Id IN: Trigger.new]; 

if(!CampaignList.isEmpty() && CampaignList.size()>0)
{
    OnCampaignBeforeDeleteHelperClass.OnCampaignBeforeDeleteMethod(CampaignList);
}

}
```

The idea here is to only run the 'before delete' trigger on campaigns that have a different value on the Campaign Member status than 'Send'. 
If there are campaigns on that criteria, invoke the this helper class:

```
public class OnCampaignBeforeDeleteHelperClass {

public static void OnCampaignBeforeDeleteMethod(List<Campaign> campaignList)
{
    //We find the running user Id.
    Id currentUserId = UserInfo.getUserId(); 

    //We find the Profile Name and Profile Id from the current User
    User currentLoggedInUser = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name, Profile.Id FROM User WHERE Id =: currentUserId]; 
    String userProfileId = currentLoggedInUser.ProfileId; 
    String userProfileName = currentLoggedInUser.Profile.Name;      

    if(currentLoggedInUser.Profile.Name =='System Administrator')
    {
        delete campaignList;
    }else{
        for(Campaign ca: campaignList)
        {
            ca.addError('This campaign can\'t be delete'); 
        }
    }
  }

}
```

There we get the current user's profile and make sure that it is an admin, if not, fire an error.

Like I said before, I haven't tested this code and it is a kind of guideline for you to experiment.I hope it helps.

Comment: @viasur- i found that if I am a campaign owner and my role is "USA sales" then anyone else in the samesame role as me could  also delete the campaign.(2) there is a a standard set of campaign member status  values for all campaigns. For eg proposed , sent, attended, no show , declined. So I am trying to say if an campaign members are past the sent status then campaign can't be delayed

Comment: @Masond, you need to check if there are sharing rules in place or what type of Managed Sharing are you using. It is possible that all "Use Sales" profiles can delete Campaigns. You need to make sure that the rights on deletion for campaigns is clear and based on that you can write a trigger to efficiently execute your business logic.

Comment: Campaign sharing currently allows users within the same role to Read/Write. Thats why i thought A Trigger may meet my business logic

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your logic in the trigger body. The best practice is to use **[Logic-less triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#Logic-less_Triggers)**

> #### Logic-less Triggers
>
> Another widely-recognized best practice is to make your Triggers logic-less. That means, the role of the Trigger is just to delegate the logic responsibilities to some other handler class. There are many reasons to do this. For one, testing a Trigger is difficult if all of the application logic is in the trigger itself. If you write methods in your Triggers, those can’t be exposed for test purposes. You also can’t expose logic to be re-used anywhere else in your org. Good old OO principles tell us that this is a bad practice. And to top it all off, cramming all of your logic into a Trigger is going to make for a mess one day. To remedy this scenario, just create a handler class and let your Trigger delegate to it. 
>   Here is an example:
>
> ```
> trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
>     OpportunityTriggerHandler.handleAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
> }
> ```
>
> And the handler class:
>
> ```
> public class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
>     public static void handleAfterInsert(List opps) {
>         // handler logic
>     }
> }
> ```

I prefer a slightly different pattern than what's in the article, but the point is that you should try to minimize the logic you have in your trigger. But the handler shouldn't really answer *how* questions, so much as just *what* questions. The *how* should be laid out in a [Service Layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_patterns_sl). You basically need two methods, one to filter out records whose deletion is prevented, and another to actually perform the validation. It's not as necessary to separate out the filter concern with validation, but it's a good practice to get into and certainly makes things easier to test. Here's a rough outline of what an ideal service would look like:

```
public with sharing class CampaignService
{
    public static List<Campaign> getUndeleteableCampaigns(List<Campaign> records)
    {
        List<Campaign> undeleteableCampaigns = new List<Campaign>();
        if (/*check for admin profile*/) return undeleteableCampaigns;

        Map<Id, Campaign> requeriedCampaigns = new Map<Id, Campaign>([
            SELECT (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers WHERE Status = 'Sent' LIMIT 1)
            FROM Campaign WHERE Id IN :campaigns AND OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        ]);
        for (Campaign record : records)
        {
            if (record.OwnerId != UserInfo.getUserId())
                undeleteableCampaigns.add(record);
            else if (!requeriedCampaigns.get(record.Id).CampaignMembers.isEmpty())
                undeleteableCampaigns.add(record);
        }
        return undeleteableCampaigns;
    }
    public static void validate(List<Campaign> records, String message)
    {
        for (Campaign record : records) record.addError(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like Adrian said, you should always avoid inserting any logic on your triggers, but that adds complexity to your code. The way to go is to use a Trigger Handler to control all trigger operations. It will also help you to have control over the execution order, which is probably the main reason for using a trigger handler.